# How to hide items on Main Activity after a Login?

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. The Main Activity and Login Activity. I already have a bunch of code in the Main Activity that is programmed to hide items when the int value is set to a specific number. But the problem is, how can I make it where after I login, it should hide all the items after sending the new int value?

In this case, how can I make it where after I login as UserAccount 1, it should hide menuItem_manage_geofence?

This is the method that I use to call the Login class from the Navigation Drawer.

```
                    Intent loginActivityIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);                     
                    startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
```

And my if methods to hide items

```
    if (UserAccountType == 0) {
        menuItem_manage_geofence.setVisible(false);
        menuItem_login_out.setVisible(false);
        menuItem_acccount_management.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (UserAccountType == 1) {
        menuItem_login_in.setVisible(false);
        menuItem_manage_geofence.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (UserAccountType == 2) {
        menuItem_login_in.setVisible(false);
        menuItem_manage_geofence.setVisible(true);
    }

    if (UserAccountType == 9) {
        Log.d(TAG, ehc.error_debug_mode);
        Toast.makeText(this, ehc.error_debug_mode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult and after successfully logging-in then on your MainActivity override onActivityResult to handle the response back from LogInActivity.  On success you hide the view you want.

Answer (score 0):

Send your UserAccountType value in intent.

```
Intent loginActivityIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);                     

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("UserAccountType",your value);
                loginActivityIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
```

And in onCreate get the value and check for it.

Comment: Where do I check the value? On the Main Activity or the Login Activity onCreate?

Comment: In Login Activity's onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent loginActivityIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class); 
loginActivityIntent.putExtra("userType",yourvalue);                     
startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
```

And in MainActivity();

```
Intent in = getIntent();
int userType = in.getExtras("userType");
```

Answer (score 0):

To move Login Activity to MainActivity you should use intent like that:
In **Login Activity**

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("accountType",1);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In **MainActivity**

```
int UserAccountType =getIntent.getIntExtra("accountType");
```

After this you may check the condition in MainActivity

Comment: There's a problem with this. It works, but there is potential for memory leak here as I can hit the back button and it returns to the previous activity state.

Comment: But if you use finish() method in LoginAcativity then How it will show again on BackPress.

Comment: Right after I login, it does what I want it to do and hides the items. However, when you hit the back button, it goes back to the previous activity state where the buttons are shown.

Comment: Which is your previous activity ?Is IT loginActivity or any other?

Comment: MainActivity then LoginActivity

Comment: It means your LoginActivity create more then one instance or you can say that your LoginActivity also called somewhere else.

Comment: I added finish(); right after I call the LoginActivity intent. Hitting the back button simply closes the app instead of going back. Hopefully this doesn't cause memory leaks.